# In Julia is big"123" a macro, function, or something else?

Tags: julia, arbitrary-precision

As a newcomer to Julia this month, Sept. 2018, I am just getting used to the initially unfamiliar "@" symbol for macros and "!" symbol for functions with mutable inputs.  Am I right to assume that these are merely stylistic symbols for humans to read, and that they do not really provide any information to the compiler?

I bring this up in the context of the following code that does not seem to match the style of a macro, a function, or anything else in Julia I am aware of.  I am specifically asking about big"1234" below:

```
julia> big"1234"  # big seems to be neither a macro or a function.
1234

julia> typeof(big"1234")
BigInt

julia> typeof(BigInt(1234))
BigInt
```

My question is: What is big in big"1234"?

Edit: I think I got my answer based on a comment at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/bigfloat-promotion-rules-and-constants-in-functions/14573/4

"Note that because decimal literals are converted to floating point numbers when parsed, BigFloat(2.1) may not yield what you expect. You may instead prefer to initialize constants from strings via parse, or using the big string literal.

```
julia> BigFloat(2.1)
2.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625

julia> big"2.1"
2.099999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999986"
```

Thus, based on the above comment, big in big"1234" is a "big string literal."

Edit 2:  The above is a start at the answer, but the accepted answer below is much more complete.

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Non-Standard-String-Literals-1

Comment: also, '@' is not a stylistic choice, afaik. The @ is spotted by the interpreter / compiler and that object is interpreted as a macro.  Also, I wouldn't call '!' a stylistic choice either, it's a strongly encouraged naming convention, since there is no other way to convey the important information of whether a function mutates its argument or not.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are Non-Standard String Literals. They tell the compiler that `xyz"somestring"` should be parsed via a macro function named `@xyz_str`.

The difference between `BigFloat(2.1)` and `big"2.1"` is that the former does convert the standard `Float64` representation of the "numeric" literal 2.1 to  `BigFloat` but the latter parses the string `"2.1"` directly (without interpreting it as a numeric literal)  with the macro `@big_str` to compute the BigFloat representation.

You can also define your Non-Standard String Literals. `LaTeXStrings.jl` for example uses it to make it easier to type LaTeX equations.

Please take a look at: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Non-Standard-String-Literals-1

Comment: I am liking Julia better all the time.  Thanks for the great answer!